# Ajuda para interromper loop

Tags: c++

Sou iniciante em C++ e estou travado nesse trabalho. O código está quase completo, porém para concluir eu preciso que ele finalize o loop e imprima o que foi digitado quando o usuario digitar 'fim' no nome, já tentei tudo que achei na internet, porém nada resolveu.

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct aluno
{
    char nome [50];
    float matricula;
    char curso [50];
    struct aluno *proximo;
}saluno;

int main ()
{

    saluno * inialuno;
    saluno * proxaluno;
    
    inialuno = (saluno *)malloc(sizeof(saluno));
    if (inialuno == NULL)
        exit(1);
    proxaluno=inialuno;

    while(1)
    {
        
        cout <<"Digite o nome:";
        cin >> proxaluno -> nome;
        cout << "Digite a matricula:";
        cin >> proxaluno -> matricula;
        cout << "Digite o curso:";      
        cin >> proxaluno -> curso;
    }
        
    while(proxaluno->proximo = NULL)
    {
                
    cout<<"\nNome: ";
    cout<<proxaluno->nome;
    cout<<"\nMatricula: ";
    cout<<proxaluno->matricula;
    cout<<"\nCurso: ";
    cout<<proxaluno->curso;
    proxaluno = proxaluno -> proximo;
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Chamar `break;` encerra o loop.

Comment: A questão é que o loop tem que parar só quando o usuario digitar 'fim' caso contrario tem que continuar entrando dados.

Comment: coloca um if após o cin do nome onde ele verifica se é fim, se sim chama um break

Answer (score 0):

//Consegui fazer dessa forma se for te ajudar de alguma forma

## include

#define TAM 50
using namespace std;

struct aluno   //Dados
{
string nome;
int  matricula;
string curso;

};

int main ()
{

```
    aluno Cadastro[TAM]; //Vetor quantidade de cadastros
    int out=0; // variavel para verificar a saida
    int cont=0; // contator para mostrar quantos cadastros foram feitos

for(int i=0;out!=1;i++){ //laco vau rodar enquanto out ser diferente de 1
    cout <<"Digite o nome:";
    cin >> Cadastro[i].nome;
    cout << "Digite a matricula:";
    cin >> Cadastro[i].matricula;
    cout << "Digite o curso:";      
    cin >> Cadastro[i].curso;
    cont ++; // conta +1 para cada castro feito
    cout<<"deseja sair? (0 - continuar / 1 - sair)"<<endl; 
    cin>>out;
    

}


for(int i=0;i<cont;i++){
    cout<<"\nNome: ";
    cout<<Cadastro[i].nome;
    cout<<"\nMatricula: ";
    cout<<Cadastro[i].matricula;
    cout<<"\nCurso: ";
    cout<<Cadastro[i].curso;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).